# How to "Fill Down" more intelligently in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula in cell A1:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,Master!A2:C560,3,0)
```

If I do "fill down" to paste this formula into all the cells below, the formula changes as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,Master!A2:C560,3,0)
=VLOOKUP(E3,Master!A3:C561,3,0)
=VLOOKUP(E4,Master!A4:C562,3,0)
etc
```

But I want it to fill down this way:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,Master!A2:C560,3,0)
=VLOOKUP(E3,Master!A2:C560,3,0)
=VLOOKUP(E4,Master!A2:C560,3,0)
etc
```

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you give this a go:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,Master!$A$2:$C$560,3,0)
```

An then copy/fill down. The <kbd>$</kbd> sign in front of the letter keeps the column constant when you copy it. The $ in front of the number keeps the row constant when you copy. You can place the cursor at for example A2 and type function key <kbd>F4</kbd>. First time you type <kbd>F4</kbd> you get $A$2. Type <kbd>F4</kbd> once more and you get A$2, next time you get $A2 and when you press it the fourth time you get back to A2.

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: Works, just what I wanted

Comment: +1 Nice trick with F4. Didn't know that o_o